# Excel VBA code to fetch value/maltiple value from web site

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fetch data from http://www.dsebd.org/displayCompany.php?name=LINDEBD by using VBA code in excell.

trying to get the follwing data from this links

Total No. of Outstanding Securities
Sector 
Company Name

am trying with,

```
    Sub GetData()
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "http://www.dsebd.org/displayCompany.php?name=LINDEBD"

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading

Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
For Each itm In Results
    If itm.classname = "lgn" Then
        dd = itm.getAttribute("href")
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
' if you wnat to click the link
    itm.Click
' otherwise
    'Range("a1").Value = dd
    MsgBox dd
End Sub
```

Is it possible to collect data from this site

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you have there?

Comment: runtime error 404, 
obejct required. 
I think something wrong here, 
If itm.classname = "lgn" Then
        dd = itm.getAttribute("href")

Comment: Commenting out `itm.Click` stops the error, but `dd` is `NULL` at the end, as the code cannot find any `classname` of `lgn`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to iterate the table(table), then you iterate the rows(tr), then within that you iterate the cells(td).  These are not links on this page.

Note: The following will get you the value you seek, but this code will be subject to constant change if the website changes.

```
Sub GetData()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "http://www.dsebd.org/displayCompany.php?name=LINDEBD"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url
        .Top = 50
        .Left = 530
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading

    Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each itm In Results
        Set rowAlt = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("alt")
        For Each itmTR In rowAlt
            Set tdValues = itmTR.getElementsByTagName("td")
            If tdValues.Item(0).innerText = "Total No. of Outstanding Securities" Then
                MsgBox tdValues.Item(1).innerText 'the value you seek
                Exit Sub 'don't continue this loop
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```